# How to display only few pages of magazine ebook in turn.js

Tags: javascript, html, turnjs

I create magazine ebook with *turn.js*. **Every pages of ebook is images.** I create 52 pages. 
When I host the ebook to my website. **My ebook only can be seen after all pages have been loaded**

My question is :
***How to display only first page (ebook cover) or when user click next arrow, user see next pages in turn.js ?***

Do you ask what I do ? I just put images of pages **inside folder pages**. I didn't do anything :
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to enable either loading through Ajax requests dynamically if it properly supports that per-page or use an alternative that supports lazyloading.

In case of the latter you might have to resort to a paid alternative like [this](http://codecanyon.net/item/diamond-flipbook-jquery/3146425) one which seemingly supports lazyloading.

Comment: thank you, for the answer. I want to ask... is that paid alternative need programming knowledge ? because I must teach creating ebook to other officers who don't know about programming

Comment: Once it's implemented, no. It'll take some time and effort implementing it though, but that would be just on your end.